# css selector for lasts elements in nodes

Tags: html, css, tree, css-selectors, html-lists

I need to choose all lasts elements in specific nodes. My question is: What the selector should be in that case ?

There are approximate view of html-code below. Need to choose all lasts `li` in `ul` which is inside `li.node`(`li` with class node).

```css
.node>ul>li:last-child {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>xxx</li>
  <li>www</li>
  <li class='node'>
    <ul>
      <li>ddedede</li>
      <li>dededed</li>
      <li class='node'>
        <ul>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>dedede</li>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>defefefe</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>vrvrvrvr</li>
  <li>vvrvrvr</li>
</ul>
```

That selector doesn't solve the problem.

```
.node > ul > li:last-child {
  color: red
}
```

So, I should clarify my question. I have dynamically generated html-code of tree-view (I can't edit html-code). So, I need to choose all lasts li inside li.node which don't have class .node (on the picture below you can see examples (circled bold red) elements li which I need to choose using specific css-selector, the shown html-code is shown for sample demonstration). But what kind of selector should be ?

Thank you in advance !

[image]

Comment: you want to select the li above the first  <li class='node'> and the last ?
please bold what you want to select

Comment: I updated my answer with a jQuery method as i don't think you can find a 
 pure CSS solution for this, so you can check if intrested

Answer (score 3):

You selector is correct and working fine BUT your are selecting two elements like you can see below:

[image]

That's why you have all the elements in red. Instead you may use this selector if you want to target only the last `li`:

```css
.node > ul > li:not(.node):last-child {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>xxx</li>
  <li>www</li>
  <li class='node'>
    <ul>
      <li>ddedede</li>
      <li>dededed</li>
      <li class='node'>
        <ul>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>dedede</li>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>defefefe</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>vrvrvrvr</li>
  <li>vvrvrvr</li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

I think you cannot find a CSS selector to select your element like you want but here is a jQuery solution if you want:

```js
$('.node > ul').each(function() {
 $(this).find(' > li:not(.node):last').css('color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>xxx</li>
  <li>www</li>
  <li class='node'>
    <ul>
      <li>ddedede</li>
      <li>dededed</li>
      <li class='node'>
        <ul>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>dedede</li>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>defefefe</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>vrvrvrvr</li>
  <li>vvrvrvr</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution is to give a different class name from the parent class name.

```css
.node1 > ul > li:last-child {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>xxx</li>
  <li>www</li>
  <li class='node'>
    <ul>
      <li>ddedede</li>
      <li>dededed</li>
      <li class='node1'>
        <ul>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>dedede</li>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>defefefe</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>vrvrvrvr</li>
  <li>vvrvrvr</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

You may need to tweek your html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
li:last-child {
    background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li>xxx</li>
  <li>www</li>
  <li class='node'>
    <ul>
      <li>ddedede</li>
      <li>dededed</li>
      <li class='node'></li>
        <ul>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>dedede</li>
          <li>dededede</li>
          <li>defefefe</li>
        </ul>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>vrvrvrvr</li>
  <li>vvrvrvr</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Is ist the result you expecting? Try it here https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FNV0QCY8G4IP